# Using realloc in self-made string struct in C - possible memory leak?

Tags: c, function, pointers, malloc

As an exercise I am implementing a string "class" in C with the use of function pointers.

Here is the beginning where I define the struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct SString* String;

struct SString
{
    char*   (*get)(const void* self);
    void    (*set)(const void* self, char* value);
    int     (*length)(const void* self);
    void    (*destroy)(void* self);
    char*   str;
    int     isInit;
};
```

And here are my "methods" of interest:

```
void setString(const void* self, char* value)
{
    /* Allocate an extra char for the null terminator, otherwise heap corruption happens */
    /* If string is not init, realloc works with NULL and acts like malloc */
    /* Once it is init, it will work on the pointer like realloc */
    ((String)self)->str = (char*)realloc( ((!((String)self)->isInit) ? NULL : ((String)self)->str) , (sizeof(char) * strlen(value))+1 );
    strcpy(((String)self)->str,value);
}   

void destroyString(void* self)
{
    free(((String)self)->str);
    free(self);
}

String newString(char* value)
{
    String self     = (String)malloc(sizeof(struct SString));
    self->get       = &getString;
    self->set       = &setString;
    self->length    = &lengthString;
    self->destroy   = &destroyString;
    self->isInit    = 0;    /* Malloc str for the first time */

    self->set(self,value);
    self->isInit    = 1;    /* Subsequent set() will realloc from now on */
    return self;
}
```

And my main just to test the stuff:

```
int main(void)
{
    String s = newString("Original init string");
    printf("%s\nIt is %d chars long.\n\n",s->get(s),s->length(s));
    s->set(s,"This is a test of a pseudo string class");
    printf("%s\nIt is %d chars long.\n\n",s->get(s),s->length(s));


    s->destroy(s);
    s = newString("Hello");
    printf("%s\nIt is %d chars long.\n\n",s->get(s),s->length(s));
    s->set(s,"Resetting the string once again and then deleting");
    puts(s->get(s));
    s->destroy(s);

    return 0;
}
```

On the surface, everything works, and I get the output that is expected.
However, I feel like I am doing some hackery with my setString() function which switches how realloc() will act.
When I call my destroyString() function and free the self "instance" and str in the struct, I'm quite sure that the next time I call newString(), it will reset everything, so the realloc is working on a new pointer, and the old one has been freed. So in theory there shouldn't be any memory leaks.

I am only using a single set function for both initializing and subsequent setting because I feel it is a more elegant solution than having multiple functions for initalizing and subsequent sets, but the tradeoff has ended me with some realloc() hackery which I am not too sure it is completely sound.

Comment: Are you sure you get any benefit from those member function pointers?  It seems unlikely to me that they provide value.  You also don't record how big the string that's allocated is — is that intentional?  It seems likely to lead to unnecessary reallocations.  You definitely have an incipient memory leak — if the `realloc()` fails, you've lost the pointer to the previous allocation because you just overwrote it with a null pointer.  The `x = realloc(x, new_size)` idiom is dangerous because of that.

Comment: That's quite a lot of totally pointless state that you make each instance of your string struct carry around, don't you think? The trick C++ does is it doesn't store member functions or member functions pointers in its objects. Nonvirtual C++ member functions are basically syntactic sugar for regular freestanding functions that take an object pointer as their first argument.

Comment: I'm not convinced by `isInit` either; if the `str` is NULL, `realloc()` will work correctly; and if it is not null it will work correctly.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: It would guess the reason the OP uses function pointers is the same as the reason they pass `self` as `void *` pointer (instead of `struct SString *` pointers). They want these functions to be overridable by "derived" classes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thanks. I realized the `isInit` was redundant, so I got rid of it and initially make `str` = NULL, so when I pass it to `realloc()` the first time it will allocate the memory and subsequent calls will reallocate. As for the `realloc()` leaking memory in case it fails, would an appropriate solution be to test if `str` is NULL after reallocating and then printing an error and quitting? 
However, If it fails, he original pointer is lost anyway, so that leaks. Is there a safer way to reallocate then?

As for not keeping length, I overlooked it and will add it in

Comment: Is the use of `const void *self` in the `setString` (`set`) method appropriate?  You cast away the constness in the code, but you can't really claim the string is constant when you are about to set its value, can you?  I think you should drop the `const` there.

Comment: The standard technique is to use an intermediate variable: `void *newspace = realloc(oldspace, newsize); if (newspace != 0) { oldspace = newspace; oldsize = newsize; …copy new data… }` — and you have a decision to make about what to do for the failure case.  Note that `realloc()` preserves the original data — you don't care about that, so you might be better off with `free()` and `malloc()` than using `realloc()` which might have to make an unnecessary copy for you.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct, but not the best possible one. There's nothing explicitly wrong with the `realloc`.

`isInit` is not needed however. `realloc` should be defined for NULL everywhere. `malloc(n)` is just `realloc(NULL, n)` on some systems.

Comment: You say 'on some systems'; surely, on all systems supporting C89 or later (meaning 'all C systems' these days), the effects of `malloc(n)` and `realloc(NULL, n)` are the same — though neither need be implemented in terms of the other.

Comment: Also note the 'incipient memory leak' part of my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38947135/using-realloc-in-self-made-string-struct-in-c-possible-memory-leak#comment65249457_38947135) to the main question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's why I said "is" and not "behaves like". Sure, they behave the same, but systems are free to have separate implementations for both code paths.

Comment: OK: we seem to have inverse interpretations of the meanings of 'is' and 'behaves like'.

Comment: huh? "is" == on some systems there's `#define malloc(n) realloc(NULL, n)`. "behaves like" == they have the same observable effect, regardless of simplementation.